AT25SF081 SPI Flash waveform timing verification
I am again looking at Figure 11-1 Read Manufacturer and Device ID Signal for the Flash device in the title.
I have created this diagram to describe my plan for implementing this operation:

As can be seen in the diagram, my FPGA will provide the system with a 12MHz clock.
On the SI side:

tCLKL > 5ns
tCLKH > 5ns
tCSLS > 5ns
tDS > 2ns
tDH > 2ns

Should be satisfied as essentially all of the values CLKL, CLKH, CSLS, DSDH in my diagram above evaluate to around 42ns.
On the SO side:

tv < 7ns
tDIS < 7ns

Should be satisfied, as I am trying to initiate a sample from the SO line exactly at a falling edge.
I.e. V = 0ns, DIS = 0ns
Have I made a mistake here?

It does not look like you made a mistake.
Your waveforms should satisfy the timing requirements of the Flash device.  You will know for sure when you connect your FPGA to the Flash, and you read the 3 ID bytes in the FPGA: 0x1F, 0x85 and 0x01.  As you stated, driving the clock at 12MHz gives you plenty of time to meet the specifications.
